# HTML div tags overlapping each other

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my div tags that my sidebar and content appears under my header when I resize window.

[When the window is maximized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TivJi.jpg)

[When the window is resized to a smaller size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFn3A.jpg)

Here is my CSS code:

```
    .header {
        height: 15%;
        width:100%;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
    }

    .sidebar {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 85%;
        float: left;
        width: 15%;
    }

    .content {
        float: right;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 85%;
        width: 85%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

I am also using a container to wrap the page content:

```
    .container {
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML too?

Comment: or better yet, create a [codepen](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar example

Comment: Hi, here is my full asp page code: http://pastebin.com/5xA6xeU6

Answer (score 0):

Put `position: relative;` on sidebar and content:

```
.sidebar {
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        height: 85%;
        float: left;
        width: 15%;
        position: relative;
    }

.content {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 85%;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried it, but it didn't work. Here is my full asp page code: http://pastebin.com/5xA6xeU6

Comment: Also put it on header.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use float for making layouts, it's not ment to do that, and gets you into problems like this. Float is ment to place block-elements in a text like this: [image]

you could simply fix this by using `position: absolute;`

```css
     .header {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
    
            height: 15%;
            width:100%;
            margin-bottom:0px;
            padding-bottom:0px;
            background: red;
            color: white;
        }
    
        .sidebar {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 15vh;
           
            padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            height: 85vh;
            width: 15vw;
          
            background: orange;
            color: white;

        }
    
        .content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 15vh;
            left: 15vw;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0; 
            
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  This is the header
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  This is the sidebar
</div>

<div class="content">
  This is the content
</div>
```

Comment: There are many other and better ways to position elements on a page than position absolute. Float is commonly used, [Bootstrap](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css) for example uses floats (I believe they are swapping to display flex? don't quote me on that). Another way is `display: inline-block` but you need a fallback for it to be supported in IE7 (if you need to support that)

Comment: Hi I tried it but It also didn't work. Here is my full code for the asp page:  http://pastebin.com/5xA6xeU6

Comment: Alexander, you're correct, but everyone uses this "hacky" float. Even big companies and libraries. The fact that it's used widely doesn't say it's correct. I'm still waiting for the day when we can safely use flexbox, but unfortunately it's still not "safe"

Comment: Eren, I'm sorry, I don't have enough time to read all that, couldn't you get my snippet to work either?

Comment: Hi Ron, your snippet normally works but in my asp project it doesn't cause the same behavior. But thanks for your interest, I very much appreciate it.